# Hotkey - Fortify until healed?

Tags: civilization-6

I can fortify using <kbd>F</kbd>

How can I fortify until healed?

It used to be the <kbd>H</kbd> key in Civ-5

Comment: The lack of hotkeys in Civ6 is one of the few things I'm quite sad about, unfortunately :(  I wouldn't be surprised if there isn't one for it (by default).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there isn't a default hotkey for that action (see [this list of default hotkeys](http://civ6.gamepedia.com/How_To_Play_Guide_for_Civ_6#Keyboard_Controls_.2F_Hotkeys) for example).

However, you may be able to add it.  You can add hotkeys in the `options` menu, if it's available as an action to hotkey there.

If not, you may have additional options for hotkey-assigning by editing the .lua file responsible for input actions.  As [this PC Invasion article explains](http://www.pcinvasion.com/civilization-vi-tips-etc), you can edit the file `C:\Wherever you have steam installed\Steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier’s Civilization Vi\Base\Assets\UI\WorldInput.lua` in a text editor, and add hotkey assignments there.  The syntax is fairly straightforward, things like:

```
if( uiKey == Keys.VK_UP or uiKey == Keys.W)
```

for changing the camera UP control to W (part of assigning them to WASD).

Comment: I'll try to remember to update this answer when I get home from work and can verify this in the game.

Comment: Actually, there is a typo. It should say `if(uiKey == Keys.VK_UP or uiKey == Keys.W)` Note the two equal signs instead of three.